# What is the best way to registering multiple services?

Tags: asp.net-core, design-patterns

I already know, to register customized managers same as 'Identity.UserManager', we have to register them.
but there is any way to prevent register multi-managers?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to #GOF, the best way is using 'Decorator Design Pattern':

a) Creating main class Managers/DecoratorManager.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace MyProject_WebMVC.Managers
{
    public interface IDecoratorManager { }
    public class DecoratorManager : IDecoratorManager
    {
        protected Data.ApplicationDbContext DB { get; }
        protected UserManager<Models.User> UserManager { get; }
        public DecoratorManager(Data.ApplicationDbContext dbContext,
            UserManager<Models.User> userManager)
        {
            DB = dbContext;
            UserManager = userManager;
        }
        protected DecoratorManager(DecoratorManager manager)
        {
            DB = manager.DB;
            UserManager = manager.UserManager;
        }
    }
}
```

b) Register it by Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    //! Custom storage manager
    services.AddScoped<Managers.IDecoratorManager, Managers.DecoratorManager>();
    ...
}
```

c) Inject decorator on Views/_VeiwImports.cs:

```
@inject Managers.IDecoratorManager Manage
```

d) Define your manager like this, Ex. ProfileManager.cs:

```
namespace MyProject_WebMVC.Managers
{
    public class ProfileManager : DecoratorManager
    {
        public ProfileManager(IDecoratorManager manager) : base(manager as DecoratorManager) { }
        public bool IsThisWorking() => true;
    }
}
```

e) Define another manager, Ex. StorageManager.cs:

```
namespace MyProject_WebMVC.Managers
{
    public class StorageManager : DecoratorManager
    {
        public StorageManager(IDecoratorManager manager) : base(manager as DecoratorManager) { }
        public string GetWelcomeMessage() => "Hello Message";
    }
}
```

f) And now you can use it what ever you want, Ex. MyView.cshtml

```
@{
    var profileManager = new Managers.ProfileManager(Manager);
    var storageManager = new Managers.StorageManager(Manager);
}
<h1>@storageManager.GetWelcomeMessage()</h1>
@if(profileManager.IsThisWorking()) { <h2>This is grate :)</h2> }
```